# How to add new properties to HTML ImageData?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html2canvas, getimagedata

In one of my applications, I am reading picture on the canvas as ImageData.
Sample code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i+0] = 255;
    imgData.data[i+1] = 0;
    imgData.data[i+2] = 0;
    imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
}

ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);

</script>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The canvas tag is not supported in Internet
Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am passing same ImageData to various other APIs and these other APIs need unique id for each ImageData to differentiate. So, I simply modified code as shown below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i+0] = 255;
    imgData.data[i+1] = 0;
    imgData.data[i+2] = 0;
    imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
}

ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);
imgData.id = 21323;
alert("imgData.id --"+imgData.id);
imgData.picType = "Rect";
alert("imgData.picType --"+imgData.picType);
</script>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The canvas tag is not supported in Internet
Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am curious to know how it worked - addition of some properties to ImageData?

Answer (score 0):

Like everything else in javascript `ImageData` too is an object and as you might be aware adding new properties to objects in JS is a matter of obj1.prop1 = val1

Now you might ask why adding some random value to your `ImageData` didn't corrupt your image ? The answer is simple : byte representation of image is stored in `data` property of ImageData as a  [Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) .

Console dump of imageData

[image: Console dump of imageData]